# How to make Ag-grid work in Storybook

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2, storybook

I have set up ag-grid to be rendered inside Storybook. However when Storybook comes up nothing displays and the following error is displayed in the Chrome console:

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicModule)[Ng2FrameworkFactory -> BaseComponentFactory]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Ng2FrameworkFactory -> BaseComponentFactory]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for BaseComponentFactory!
    at NullInjector../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:1034)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1271)
```

I suspect this is because ag-grid is not set up correctly in the Storybook module. Here's how I have set it up - using the Strorybook decorator:

```
import { AgGridNg2 } from 'ag-grid-angular';
...

storiesOf('Order List', module)
    .addDecorator(
        moduleMetadata({
            declarations: [AgGridNg2]
        })
    )
    .add('list with orders', () => ({
        component: OrderListComponent,
        props: {
            orders: orders
        }
    }));
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong? The full project is available on [Github](https://github.com/nareshbhatia/angular-aggrid-testing-techniques), specifically the Storybook story is [here](https://github.com/nareshbhatia/angular-aggrid-testing-techniques/blob/master/src/stories/index.stories.ts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I had to import `AgGridModule` into storybook:

```
.addDecorator(
    moduleMetadata({
        imports: [AgGridModule.withComponents([])]
    })
)
```